# NSManagedObjectContext save notification on background thread

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I have NSManagedObjectContext in background thread. When context in main thread save context on background thread don't know about it. 
I try to use NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification on main context but then i can't run marge methode in background thread. bellow is my code.

```
NSNotificationCenter *nc = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
[nc addObserver:self selector:@selector(managedObjectContextDidSave:) name:NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification object:nil];


if (![[currentThread threadDictionary] objectForKey:@"managedObjectContext"]) {
        NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];

        // Configure Managed Object Context
        [managedObjectContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator:_mOCMainSetting.persistentStoreCoordinator];
        [[currentThread threadDictionary] setObject:managedObjectContext forKey:@"managedObjectContext"];

        if (!_contextArray) {
            _contextArray = [NSArray array];
        }
        NSMutableArray *mutableContextArray = [_contextArray mutableCopy];
        [mutableContextArray addObject:managedObjectContext];
        _contextArray = mutableContextArray;
    }

    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [[currentThread threadDictionary] objectForKey:@"managedObjectContext"];
    options = (Options*)[context objectWithID:_optionsID];

    return options;
}

   - (void)managedObjectContextDidSave:(NSNotification *)notification {
//    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        for (NSManagedObjectContext *context in _contextArray) {
            [context mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:notification];
        }
//    });
}
```

can you ask me how to run merge method in correct thread.

Comment: Use the MOC instance method  `performBlock` on the MOC corresponding to the thread you want to save on, and the code in the block will be queued on the thread you want.

Comment: Ok. If i understood ok. Everything in performBlock is run in MOC thread?

Comment: Yes. If "myMOC" is a mainQueueConcurrency MOC, `[myMOC performBlock:...]` goes to the main thread.   If the MOC's got a private queue, it goes to the MOC's private queue.